# Need help for finding a correlation in this dataset

Tags: r, tableau-api, correlation

i want to find a correlation between discount amount and order frecuency in this dataset:

https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/zusmani/pakistans-largest-ecommerce-dataset

i just try it between 'discount amount' and 'Qty ordered' variable and there's no correlation, so i want to try to change the independent variable into 'order frecuency'. Or maybe 'discount amount by month' and 'order frequency by month' but i dont have any clue how to do it.

i believe there's a positive correlation between discount amount and the order, because i just check it when doing EDA's, but i have an issues when doing a scatter plot chart about it.

i try it in tableau, but if you try in another tools like phyton, excel or anything else its okay. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the "order frequency" that you mean. I guess that is (qty_order / grand total).

```
library(tidyverse)

data01 <- rawdata |>                          # this is calculating the total correlation
    mutate(order_freq = qty_ordered / grand_total) |>    # calculate the order_freq
    select(discount_amount, order_freq) |>    # remove other column for simplicity (not neccesary)
    filter(is.finite(order_freq)) |>          # remove rows with infinite value
    cor()                                     # calculate the correlation

data02 <- rawdata |>    # this is calculating the correlation of each month
    mutate(order_freq = qty_ordered / grand_total) |> 
    select(Month, discount_amount, order_freq) |> 
    filter(!is.na(Month) & is.finite(order_freq)) |> 
    group_by(Month) |>                                   # calculate the correlation
    summarise(Corr = cor(discount_amount, order_freq))   #  of each month separately

> print(data01)
                discount_amount   order_freq
discount_amount     1.000000000 -0.001621597
order_freq         -0.001621597  1.000000000

> print(data02)
# A tibble: 12 x 2
   Month     Corr
   <int>    <dbl>
 1     1 -0.0113 
 2     2  0.0628 
 3     3 -0.0256 
 4     4  0.00990
 5     5 -0.00290
 6     6 -0.00881
 7     7 -0.00724
 8     8 -0.0294 
 9     9 -0.0254 
10    10 -0.0329 
11    11 -0.0313 
12    12 -0.00980
```